# Regular expression matching a URL of PDF in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have an ORACLE table with a column called 'Links' that has URLs. I would like to use SQL SELECT to display URLs from the column that are URLs of a pdf (eg. http://www.abc.com/1/def.pdf). I have never used regular expression in SQL SELECT WHERE clause. Please help

Comment: What's wrong with `LIKE '%.pdf'`?

Comment: Going to have to agree with David. A like statement with a wildcard would be best.

Comment: ... or `LIKE 'http://%.pdf'`?

Comment: Thanks all! If I have to find all URLs which are NOT pdf?

Comment: `NOT LIKE 'http://%.pdf'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Links
FROM MyTable
WHERE Links LIKE 'http://%.pdf'
```

Comment: Thanks kol. If I have to find all other urls that are NOT a PDF?

Comment: Another: SELECT Links FROM MyTable **MINUS** SELECT Links FROM MyTable WHERE Links LIKE 'http://%.pdf'